# Populate javascript variable from ViewBag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, viewbag

I saw on stackoverflow we can do this to populate js variables with ViewBags (with razor):

```
@{
    var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var userInfoJson = jss.Serialize(ViewBag.User);
 }
```

with this:

```
<script>
 //use Json.parse to convert string to Json
  var userInfo = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(userInfoJson)');
</script>
```

I want to do the same thing with aspx not razor. Can you help me?

Comment: '@Html.Raw(userInfoJson)' ---> '<%=userInfoJson%>'

Comment: You don't need JSON.parse

Comment: @userfloflo Are you asking for **ASP.Net Web Form** or **ASPX View Engine**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my controller:

```
Viewbag.test="Thanks to you it works!"
```

In my aspx:

```
public String test {get; set;}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  test = ViewBag.test; 
}

<script>
  alert('<%=test%>');
</script>
```

Result: Thanks to you it works!

Answer (score 0):

Add a *public* property to your page and populate it on Page Load (you may have to do it on Page Init, I can't remember which processes first).

```
public UserType UserToSerialize {get; set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserToSerialize = LoadUser(); //I assume you've got some magic to do this already
}
```

Markup:

```
<script>
  var userInfo = JSON.parse("<%# new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(UserToSerialize) %>");
</script>
```

Notice I use `UserToSerialize` to avoid interfering with the [Page.User property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user(v=vs.110).aspx).